# Criar um vetor 2D a partir de um vetor 1D em Python

Tags: python-2.7, array-multidimensional

- Possuo um vetor com os seguintes valores:

  a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
- Preciso criar vetor 2D com esses valores. Por exemplo, ele teria que ficar assim:

  b = [[10, 20], [30, 40], [50, 60], [70, 80]]

Por gentileza, alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

Desde já grato, aos que puderem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer algo assim:

```
b = [a[i:i+2] for i in range (0, len(a), 2]
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado. Funcionou corretamente.